# Difference in SPListItem[field_Name] vs SPListItem.Properties[field_Name] in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Is there any difference in below statement or are they same?

`SPListItem[field_Name]` **vs** `SPListItem.Properties[field_Name]`

Where **field_Name** is column name in a sharepoint list.

And which one is better to use in reference to optimaztion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both are different. `SPListItem.Properties` is a `hashtable` which can be used to store key value pairs. It is also known as List item property bag in SharePoint.

> In ASP.Net web application, whenever we need configuration data
>   (key-value pair), we store that data in web.config file in AppSetting
>   and retrieve configurations from config according to our need. Like
>   AppSetting, SharePoint provides property bag at each level for your
>   SharePoint Application Development
>   SharePoint provides Property bags to store and retrieve configuration
>   at various levels like:
>
> 1. Farm Level - SPFarm
> 2. Web Application Level - SPWebApplication
> 3. Web Level - SPWeb Level
> 4. Item Level - SPListItem

Whereas `SPListItem[field_Name]` is used to get/set value of a field in a SharePoint List item. Example to store value in list item property bag:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://aissp2013/sites/Team"))
{
    SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
    SPList list = web.Lists["Employees"];
    SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(1);
    item.Properties.Add("Employee Name", "Nadeem Yousuf");
    item.Update();
    list.Update();
}
```

See more at http://www.tekritisoftware.com/using-sharepoint-property-bag-in-your-sharepoint-application

Comment: Could you please specify the scenarios where they are used them?